# Problem setting the default wired connection

Tags: wired

I have three wired connections setting saved. I would like to have connection_1 as my default setting whenever I log-in. How can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check automatically connect on connection_1 and uncheck it from other connection :

[image]